# How can I convert android project to ionic plugin

Tags: android, plugins, ionic-framework

I need to convert android project to ionic plugin.
Can any one help me how can i do this ? I didn;t find any steps or any link regarding this
Please help me How can I convert android android project to plugin in ionic?
OR How can I create plugin in ionic ??

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is a Cordova plugin. Ionic Framework is using Cordova. The plugins are exactly the same.

You can find help on Cordova documentation :
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html